# freeradius failover when ldap not available

Tags: openldap, freeradius

I am using *freeRADIUS 3.0* with two data sources:

- users file
- *openldap*

The configuration is working fine, but when *freeRADIUS* is started at power-on, and LDAP server is not available, *freeRADIUS* complain and don't start.

So, is there a special configuration do say to *freeRADIUS*:

> "hey, you can't bind now to LDAP, never mind, use only users file as data source." ?

Update 2017.02.11 ===========
/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default and inner-tunnel files:

```
    authorize {
        filter_username
        preprocess
        auth_log
        chap
        mschap
        digest
        suffix
        eap {
           ok = return
        }
        files
        ldap {
          fail = 1
        }
        if (fail) {
          ok
        }
        expiration
        logintime
        pap
}
```

Extract from debug mode:

```
radiusd -X
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.16
...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Initialising connection pool
   pool {
        start = 0
        min = 0
        max = 32
        spare = 0
        uses = 0
        lifetime = 0
        cleanup_interval = 30
        idle_timeout = 60
        retry_delay = 30
        spread = no
   }
rlm_ldap (ldap): Loading dynamic clients
rlm_ldap (ldap): 0 of 0 connections in use.  You  may need to increase "spare"
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (0), 1 of 32 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://srv1.lan4:636
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind with uid=radius,ou=users,dc=lan1 to ldap://srv1.lan4:636 failed: Can't contact LDAP server
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening connection failed (0)
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap[312]: Error loading clients
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap[8]: Instantiation failed for module "ldap"
```

Comment: If the problem is that they run on the same server, that is more a start-up priority/dependancy  problem which can be solved by simply making freeRadius dependant on the successful start-up of the openldap server, rather than starting both concurrently.

Comment: In fact it is a needed behaviour because data in users file enable critical network connectivity and LDAP server can't be available if critical network device are not authorized by RADIUS ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the redundant section e.g.

```
authorize {
    redundant {
        ldap
        files
    }
}
```

If the first module fails, the second module will be called.

If you want the server to start if LDAP is unavailable set the [pool.start](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/raddb/mods-available/ldap#L530) configuration parameter to zero.

If you want to ignore the fact that the ldap module failed

```
authorize {
    ldap {
        fail = 1
    }
    if (fail) {
        ok
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, 'files' data store does not contain the same data as 'ldap' data store. Both are complementary data: 'files' for critical network device and 'ldap' for user's network devices. So 'redundant' can't be used because in 'instantiate {}' section of radiusd.conf we have to use a 'virtual module name' that involve 'ldap' OR 'files' but not 'ldap' AND 'files'.

Comment: What I've tryed: instantiate { ldap { fail = 1  } } but does not works: radiusd.conf[742]: Cannot set return codes in a ldap block

Comment: The problem is at ldap module init: rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind with uid=radius,ou=users,dc=lan1 to ldap://srv1.lan4:636 failed: Can't contact LDAP server
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening connection failed (0)
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap[312]: Error loading clients
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap[8]: Instantiation failed for module "ldap"

Comment: Added more notes

Comment: As you can see on my updated question, I have set your configuration including pool.start=0, but freeradius refuse starting. Could it be a bug in ldap module ?